# Unity3D comparing images

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to look at the black pixels of a picture with the black pixels of a second picture. How can I convert the apple.GetPixel(i,ii).grayscale to a Color?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ComparePictures : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D apple;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        int blackPixels = 0;
        int texWidht = (int) apple.width;
        int texHeight = (int) apple.height;
        for(int i = 0; i < texWidht; i++)
        {
            for(int ii = 0; ii < texHeight; ii++)
            {
                if(apple.GetPixel(i,ii) == Color.black)
                {
                    blackPixels ++;
                }
            }
        }
        print(blackPixels);
    }
}
```

Comment: apple.GetPixel() returns a color?

Comment: yes http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? you want to convert GetPixel().grayscale back to a color? Why dont you just not call .grayscale?

Comment: I want to count the amount of black pixels in the image. I removed the .grayscale

Comment: Your current code should work? Does it print 0? You may want to initialize int blackPixels; Remember this will only work for pure black values and not just dark ones.

Comment: Yes you are right I forgot to initialize the int blackPixels it now is. And yes the black pixels are pure black. It still prints out 0 is there somthing wrong in my write read settings of my texture because as soon as I run it the colors of my texture change and this is the only code I am running. Is there also a way to check for dark pixels instead of pure black?

Comment: O! I got it working now :) My second question remains "Is there also a way to check for dark pixels instead of pure black?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the values are dark just check the appropriate values. Here is a handy image:

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmn8p4QPwqPoJ-rFBgycXXnH2UmVCsQdZYMo3IvXF_92JIfJyUulr0r7g]

```
var color : Color = Color (.3, .4, .6);
print(color.grayscale);
```

It is all up to you to decide how dark is dark enough. Some code could be:

```
// Check if a color is over 80% dark
if(color.grayscale > 8.0)
    // Dark enough for me
```

Comment: if(apple.GetPixel(i,ii).grayscale == 1.0f)
    {
     blackPixels ++;
    } should return the same as if(apple.GetPixel(i,ii) == Color.black)
    {
     blackPixels ++;
    } right? But it doesnt :P....

Comment: first if statement returns 24.000 and the second 100.000 quite a difference haha

Comment: O whahah I see 0.0 is black an 1 is white I get it seems logical :)